# Reverse of Gabriel's Horn/Toricelli's Trumpet - need explanation of the proof

Tags: calculus, limits, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf, solid-of-revolution

I am writing an exploration on the Gabriel's Horn (Toricelli's Trumpet) and as one of my chapters I wanted to take a look at the existence of a solid of revolution with infinite volume and finite surface area. The exclusive proof I found is

> [image: here]

My problem is that I don't understand what actually happens there, as I am not familiar with the sup notation. Moreover, I don't know where the $f(x)^2 -f(1)^2$ comes from, nor why it can be transformed to an integral and later to an integral of a derivative. Why are the limits of the integral modified and where the right side of the inequality comes from? Eventually, I don't understand what $M$ means in the volume formula. It is surely beyond my current level of maths (final high school grade), and I couldn't find any proper source to understand the application of those lim sups in there. I would be grateful for a step by step  explanation, assume that I will understand basic calculus and standard limits, but nothing beyond.

Comment: I can only assume that this is badly translated from some other language. 

It *says* if $f$ is $C^1$, then both the surface area and volume are finite (which is obviously false). But what it proves (assuming the proof is correct) is that if $f$ is $C^1$ *and* the surface area is finite, then the volume is also finite.

Comment: I believe that is what it was supposed to prove. Nonetheless, I can't understand the proof - how we should understand the lim (sup) notation and how it may be converted into an integral of different limits. What is more, I don't get why the chain rule of f(x)^2 gives 2f(x)d/dxf(x) instead of simple 2f(x). Could you explain this proof in simple words, preferably without complicated mathematical notation? I can't find any proper source to learn more about sups and infs, as they always refer to seqencec, not function/integrals.

Comment: No it is not supposed to prove that both surface area and volume must be finite. It is trivial to come up with counter-examples (such as $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$). Whoever wrote this - at least the English version - was not very good at English. If they are not a native speaker, this can be understandable. Alas, some native speakers are also not very good at English.

Comment: Of course, that's what I meant - it is supposed to rather proof that volume is finite given area is finite. It still does not help me to understand the proof though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to take so long to get back, but while I get the idea the author was going for in that proof, it has so many problems. That first inequality chain - whose purpose is just to show that $f(x)$ is bounded - is broken, and I haven't figured out how to fix it. Perhaps that ridiculous statement is actually an artifact of sloppy mathematics, not sloppy translation, after all.

Besides which, this theorem is only about solids of revolution, which is just one small class of the solids you need to be concerned with. Consider a similarly shaped solid, with with square cross-sectional areas instead of circular. A minor change, but the theorem doesn't apply any longer, even if the proof were fixed.

So let me provide the outline of a different, more general, proof. Using cylindrical coordinates, consider a solid whose surface is given by a continuously differentialble function $r = R(\theta, z)$ with $R(0, z) = R(2\pi, z)$. And for convenience, I will also assume that there is a value $M$ such that if $z \ge M$, then $|R(\theta,z)| < 1$ for all $\theta$. Effectively, this means that if you go out far enough on the $z$-axis, the solid will be contained within a cylinder of radius $1$ from then on. (This assumption is not actually needed, but the proof becomes much more complicated without it, and I think you'll understand it better without the added complication.)

The differential of volume for cylindrical coordinates is $dV = r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$. The differential of surface area is $dA = ds\,dz$, where $ds$ is arclength along the curve $\theta \mapsto R(\theta, z)$ for fixed $z$. So $$ds = \sqrt {dR^2 + R^2d\theta^2} = \left(\sqrt{\frac{\partial R}{\partial \theta}^2 + R^2}\right)d\theta$$

So, surface area is given by $$A = \int dA = \int_1^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{R_\theta^2 + R^2}\,d\theta\,dz$$
And volume is given by $$V = \int dV = \int_1^\infty \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{R(\theta,z)} r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz = \frac12\int_1^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} R^2\,d\theta\,dz $$

Now we can break the area and volume up by the plane $z = M$: $A = A_1 + A_2, V = V_1 + V_2$, where
$$A_1 = \int_1^M \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{R_\theta^2 + R^2}\,d\theta\,dz,\qquad A_2 = \int_M^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{R_\theta^2 + R^2}\,d\theta\,dz\\V_1 =\frac12\int_1^M \int_0^{2\pi} R^2\,d\theta\,dz, \qquad V_2 = \frac12\int_M^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} R^2\,d\theta\,dz$$ 
$A_1$ and $V_1$ are the integrals of bounded functions over bounded regions, and therefore must be finite. For $A_2$ and $V_2$, we know that $R < 1$, and therefore $R^2 < |R|$. But then
$$\sqrt{R_\theta^2 + R^2} \ge \sqrt{R^2} = |R| > R^2 \ge \frac{R^2}2$$
From which it follows that $A_2 \ge V_2$.

If $V$ is infinite, then since $V_1$ is finite, it must be that $V_2$ is infinite. But that means $A_2$ is also infinite, and so is the full surface area $A$.

By the contrapositive, if $A$ is finite, the $V$ must be finite as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the first sight, I do notice it is a proper and accurate proof of what I was looking for. Nonetheless, in order to catch up, I need to learn more about cylindrical coordinates and their properties. Perhaps what you have laid out here follows some established rules I am not familiar with yet. I am going to come back to this thread once I gain some basic knowledge, yet for know, could you explain in simple words what does ∂ stand for in here? Also, I cannot imagine what R(0,z)=R(2π,z) tells us.

Comment: Judge the accuracy only after you understand it. Just like Cartesian coordinates express each point in space by 3 coordinates $(x, y, z)$, cylindrical coordinates express each point by three coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$, where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is this distance from the point to the $z$-axis, and $\theta$ is an angle $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ such that $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$. Because you are interested in solids extending infinitely in one direction, the radial symmetry of cylindrical coordinates about the $z$-axis make it a convenient choice for this proof.

Comment: For constant $\theta, z$, distance is the difference in $r$. Infinitesimally, this is the differential $dr$. When $r, \theta$ are constant, the distance is $dz$. But when $r, z$ are constant, the distance traveled by a change of $\theta$ is not $d\theta$, but $r\,d\theta$ (the circumference of a circle is $2\pi r$, not just the full angle of $2\pi$). Because the directions of increase for $r, \theta, z$ are always perpendicular, a differential volume is a box with sides $dr, r\,d\theta, dz$ and so has volume $dV = (dr)(r\,d\theta)(dz)$ and the diagonal is $ds =\sqrt{dr^2 + d\theta^2 + dz^2}$

Comment: $R$ is function of two variables, $\theta, z$. To differentiate it, we hold one constant while differentiating with respect to the other. This is called "partial differentiation" and is symbolized by $\partial$. I.e., $$\dfrac {\partial R}{\partial \theta}(\theta_0,z_0) = \left.\dfrac{d(R(\theta,z_0))}{d\theta}\right|_{\theta = \theta_0}$$It gets its own special name because the partial derivative depends not only on $\theta$, but also subtlely on the variable $z$ - a different set of coordinates may use the same $\theta$, but the partial derivative with respect to $\theta$ may be different.

Comment: The partial derivative symbol reminds us that this derivative depends on the whole coodinate system, not just the variable of differentiation. But the notation is unwieldly when you have to write it down a lot, so it is common to use an abbreviated version with the variable of differentiation as a subscript: $$R_\theta = \dfrac{\partial R}{\partial \theta}$$ Lastly, because an angle of $\theta = 0$ is the same direction as $\theta = 2\pi$, for $R$ to be continuous along the $+x$-axis, we must have $R(0, z) = R(2\pi,z)$.

Comment: Way too late to fix it, I see I messed up the arclength formula in my second comment above. It should be $ds = \sqrt{dr^2 + r^2\,d\theta^2 + dz^2}$. Always fun to see you've accidently dropped the key piece that was the reason you were posting in the first place!

Comment: Thank you, in fact I had been wondering whether the arclength formula was correct. What you had written made understanding the proof way easier for me and currently I am learning about cylindrical coordinates. In case I cannot get past some part of the proof, I will write here again!